# how to combine elements of array into one alert box at the end

Tags: javascript

I have a program that calculates students percentages in a class and need the final output to all be in one box. however my program currently does on alert box for each student how do I fix this?

here is the code

```
<script>
function studentName(x)
{
    while(x == '' || x >= 0 || x < 0)
    {
        if(x == '')
        {
            x = prompt('Cannot leave field blank. Enter again');
        }

        else if (x >= 0)
        {
            x = prompt('Cannot Enter a number. Enter again')
        }

        else
        {
            x = prompt('Cannot Enter a number. Enter again')
        }

    }
    return(x)
} 


function studentScore(y)
{
    while(y == '' || y > 100 || y < 0 || isNaN(y))
    {

        if (y == '')
        {
            y = parseFloat(prompt("Cannot leave field, blank please enter students score"));
        }

        else if (y > 100 || y < 0)
        {
            y = parseFloat(prompt("Invalid score, please enter a score 0-100"));
        }

        else
        {
            y = parseFloat(prompt("Invalid score, please enter a score 0-100"));
        }

    }
    return(y)
}


function another(z)
{
    while(z == '' && z != 'n' && z != 'N' && z != 'y' && z != 'Y')
    {
    while (z == '' && z != 'n' && z != 'N' && z != 'y' && z != 'Y' )
         {
            z = prompt('Invalid response, would you like to enter another score Y/N ')
         }


    while(z == 'n' || z == 'N')
        {
            Z = prompt('Would you like to enter another student')
        }

    while (z == 'y' || z == 'Y')
        {
            z = prompt("Enter another score")
        }
    }



    return(z)
}

var names = []  
var scores = []
var redo = true
var anotherName
var redo2
var retry = true
var anotherScore
var retry2
var i = 0
var a = 1
var score = 0
    while(redo == true)
    {
        var studentNames = prompt('Enter student name');
                var name = studentName(studentNames);
                names.push(name)
        while(retry == true)
        {
            var studentScores = parseFloat(prompt('Enter student score'));
            score = score + studentScore(studentScores);

            retry = prompt('Enter another score? Y/N');
            retry = another(retry);                   /**/
            if(retry == 'y' || retry == 'Y')
            {
                retry = true
                a++
            }
            else if(retry == 'n' || retry == 'N')
            {
                retry = false
            }
        }
        score = score / a
        scores[i] = score
        redo = prompt('Enter another student? Y/N');
        redo = another(redo);                            /**/

        if(redo == 'y' || redo == 'Y')
        {
            redo = true
            retry = true
            i++;
            a = 1
            score = 0
        }
        else if(redo == 'n' || redo == 'N')
        {
            redo = false
        } 
    }
    var message = ""
    for(y=0; y < names.length; y++)
    {
        alert(names[y] + " - " + scores[y]);
    }
```

again I have a program that calculates students percentages in a class and need the final output to all be in one box. however my program currently does on alert box for each student how do i fix this and get all of the students names into one final alert box?

Comment: do you have some data to test it?

Comment: i dont have any screenshots but you could copy paste the code into a text editor of some sort like sublime text save the program and run it to see the issue. just hit enter a student with a score of any number and hit n for enter another score y for enter another student then enter one more score and respond n to entering another score and another student it will have however many alert boxes as the number of students you entered and i need just one box

Answer (score 1):

You are getting separate alerts because you're calling `alert` on every iteration with individual values. One solution could be to combine the names and the corresponding scores in a new array and call `alert` once on this array. Using `join('\n')` on the new array will convert the array elements to string and separate each array elements with new line, for the sake of formatting. Just change the last part with:

```
let roster = [];
for(let y=0; y < names.length; y++) {
    roster.push(names[y] + " - " + scores[y]);
}
alert(roster.join('\n'))
```

Better yet if you save names and scores in one array from the beginning, like the `roster`. In this way you could avoid additional iteration at the end.